# How to retrieve rows of a Pandas GroupBy object in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a group by object.I want to retrieve rows of a particular column of the group by object in for loop & do some processing. For example,I'm giving here a sample code for group by object

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                             'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
```

After group by, I got following object

[image]

In a for loop I would like to do some check if it's one,two or three & then do some processing.Can you please suggest me the steps?

Comment: If you have a new question, then open a new question. Don't modify the same thing, it benefits no one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can loop in the group_by object like this :

```
for index, row in grouped:
    print (index) #index is a tuple 
    print(row) #row is a new dataframe
```

To check what you are looking for you can do this(ie: check if a value is in a certain column of a dataframe do this):

```
for index, row in grouped:
    if -0.83026 in row.get("C").values: # "C" or any column name you want
        print("hello")
```

for your data the output will be something like this :

```
('bar', 'one')
     A    B        C         D
1  bar  one -0.83026  0.983017
('bar', 'three')
     A      B         C         D
3  bar  three -0.381041  1.538971
('bar', 'two')
     A    B         C         D
5  bar  two -0.963402  0.201348
('foo', 'one')
     A    B         C         D
0  foo  one  0.691410  0.328420
6  foo  one -1.521541 -0.188345
('foo', 'three')
     A      B         C         D
7  foo  three -0.817304 -0.359331
('foo', 'two')
     A    B         C         D
2  foo  two -0.528639 -0.999301
4  foo  two -1.018919  0.661665
```

Comment: Thank you.Now I'm trying to check if -1.5522 is there in my groupby object or not. So I wrote some code, which I'm going to add in my first comment,there. I'm getting some error. Please have a look & suggest me

Comment: index are tuples and row are dataframes, update your answer

Comment: Yes I considered rows as a data frame. I have updated my error code. Can you please look & suggest me

Comment: Yes, up voted your answer. Sorry I should have done before that. Still I have issue. I'm adding in my comment section. If you can kindly provide me solution then I will accept your answer

Comment: Sorry,Admin removed my earlier modification. SO @Espoir following your suggestion I try. It worked. But for testing I used following code     `for index, row in grouped:
    if 10 in row.get("C"):         print("hello")` and 10 is not in my column C but still I got hello!!

Comment: Hi @Espoir Murhabazi, sorry I'm not getting. It's looking like same code in your comment section & I'm also getting same error. Can you please put your updated code after this comment?

Comment: I changed row.get("C") to row.get('C').values which return a list of column element, to check if an item is in that list just do if an_item in row.get("C") : I'm sure that this should works @PythonLearner

Comment: Sorry,completely confused. Actually both row.get("C")  & row.get('C') are giving me same thing.Kindly post your code below this post.My requirement is if it's matching with column C I will able to print Hello & if not matching it won't print anything. Or if you want then I can create a separate thread

Comment: **row.get("C").values** and row.get("C") are giving the same thing? @PythonLearner

Comment: Yes, I'm getting same thing. Please put your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911694/how-to-retrieve-rows-of-a-pandas-groupby-object-in-for-loop-using-if-condition