# How to retrieve rows of a Pandas GroupBy object in for loop using if Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group by object.I want to retrieve rows of a particular column of the group by object in for loop & do some processing. For example,I'm giving here a sample code for group by object

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                             'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
```

After group by, I got following object

[image]

Now I want to check if my column C has -1.5522 or 2.007514.If it matches then I will print "Hello"

Comment: please this look like a duplicate question of the prevouis one , add what you have already tried and the excpected result

Comment: I think you want to give your grouper an aggregation function. `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])` gives you a weird groupby object without any aggregation yet, `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()` or `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean()` will give you a dataframe you can iterate through like any other, using `df.iterrows().`